# Counting values embedded in strings inside a column (Google Spreadsheets)

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, formula, countif

I have a Google Survey where I created some multiple choice questions. Now, I am trying to count the responses.

```
[A]          [B]
[Response#]  [Selections]
[1]          [Apple,Orange,Banana]
[2]          [Orange,Banana]
[3]          [Apple,Orange,Banana]
[4]          [Banana]
[5]          [Apple,Banana]
[6]          [Apple,Orange]
.
```

So on my summary spreadsheet, I would like to have the totals:

```
[Favorite Fruit] [Total]
[Apple]          [4]
[Orange]         [4]
[Banana]         [5]
.
```

I tried using:

```
 =countif('Responses'!B:B,find(A2))
```

but got no results (where A2 was the word "Apple"). I know that `find` is incomplete, then I also tried putting `find(A2,'Responses'!B:B)` but that's not right. I'm stumped.

Comment: edited title for readability, added code format for readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use wildcards.. 
please try:

```
=countif('Responses'!B:B,"*"&A2&"*")
```

and see if that works ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Apple, Orange and Banana are in cells A1, A2 and A3 of your summary sheet respectively and that your data is in a seperate sheet called 'Data' in cells A1:B20, you can use the following:

`=SUMPRODUCT((NOT(ISERROR(FIND(A1, Data!$A$1:$B$20)))*1))`